# Goodness of fit of two models

Tags: goodness-of-fit, model-comparison, quantile-regression

My two models that I would like to compare are Weibull distribution and Quantile regression (in the case of Weibull distribution I have estimated the quantile curves). I would like to know if there is a metric that will allow me to analyze which of the two distributions fits the data better?

Comment: You can always try the $\chi^2$ goodness-of-fit test.

Comment: The output of quantile regression is not a distribution.  Do you only care about the values at a small number of known quantiles, or are you looking for something more generally applicable?

Comment: @jbowman You can estimate a distribution through its quantile curves and that's what I meant. I have the estimated Weibull-quantile curves and the Quantile Regression curves. I would like to see which of the two fits the data better.